# Diccionario con listas - Imprimir por consola

Tags: python, lista, diccionarios, consola

Tengo un diccionario y dentro una lista.

```
{1: ['remera', 's', 'verano', 10.2, 3]}
```

No me sirve y no me doy cuenta si definí mal el diccionario.
Entiendo que el código 1, 2, 3 sería las *keys* y el valor es la lista.

Ahora, haciendo un `for key, value in diccionario:`

Necesito que salga:

```
codigo: 1
      tipo: remera
      talle: S
      temporada: primavera
      precio: 10.23
      cantidad: 3
codigo: 2
      tipo:...
```

No me doy cuenta, cómo acceder a la lista

```
CODIGO DE ARTICULO. 
1
TIPO DE ARTICULO. 
REMERA
TALLE DEL ARTICULO. 
S
TEMPORADA DEL ARTICULO. 
PRIMAVERA
INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL ARTICULO. 
10.23
INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE ARTICULOS. 
3
CODIGO DE ARTICULO. 
0  (este 0, es el elemento 0 en el diccionario?)
{1: ['REMERA', 'S', 'PRIMAVERA', 10.23, 3]}
```

```
def cargarArticulos(x):
    codigo = int(input('CODIGO DE ARTICULO. \n'))
    while codigo != 0:
        tipo = input('TIPO DE ARTICULO. \n')
        talle = input('TALLE DEL ARTICULO. \n')
        tempo = input('TEMPORADA DEL ARTICULO. \n')
        precio = float(input('INGRESE EL PRECIO DEL ARTICULO. \n'))
        cantidad = int(input(('INGRESE LA CANTIDAD DE ARTICULOS. \n')))
        x[codigo] = [tipo, talle, tempo, precio, cantidad]
        codigo = int(input('CODIGO DE ARTICULO. \n'))
    return x

def imprimeDiccionario(inventario):
    for valor in inventario:
        print(valor)
    
x = {}
cargarArticulos(x)
imprimeDiccionario(x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para que no les digan y no les cuenten:
Lo buscado es esto:

```
def imprimir_inventario(inventario):
    for p in inventario.items():
        print(f"{inventario.get('codigo')} : {inventario.get('detalle')}")
```

Como les comente, el error estaba en la definici'on de diccionario.
Graacias, por el ayuda ofrecida.  Sigo generando fallos y buscando soluciones...

Answer (score 0):

La forma de recorrer el diccionario es:

```
for llave in diccionario:
```

Luego, puedes acceder a los elementos del diccionario con la sintaxis:

```
diccionario[llave]
```

En tu caso, esta será la lista que has almacenado. Guardando esta referencia, puedes acceder a los elementos de la lista por su índice, por ejemplo:

```
lista = diccionario[llave]
tipo = lista[0]
```

También puedes acceder a los elementos de la lista directamente sobre el diccionario, por ejemplo:

```
talla = diccionario[llave][1]
```

Mira este ejemplo que *imprime* algo similar a lo que buscas:

```
diccionario = {
      1: ['remera', 's', 'verano', 10.2, 3]
    , 2: ['pantalón', 'l', 'primavera', 15.1, 7]
}

for llave in diccionario:
    lista = diccionario[llave]
    print("código:", llave)
    print("\ttipo:\t\t", lista[0])
    print("\ttalla:\t\t", lista[1])
    print("\ttemporada:\t", lista[2])
    print("\tprecio:\t\t", diccionario[llave][3])
    print()
```

Produce esta salida:

```
código: 1
    tipo:        remera
    talla:       s
    temporada:   verano
    precio:      10.2

código: 2
    tipo:        pantalón
    talla:       l
    temporada:   primavera
    precio:      15.1
```

Comment: Creo que para este caso de uso concreto es mejor iterar el diccionario con `for llave, valor in diccionario.items()`.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma alterna seria la siguiente:

```
def imprime_diccionario(inventario):
    llaves = ["TIPO", "TALLE", "TEMPORADA", "PRECIO", "CANTIDAD"]
    for codigo in inventario:
        print("Codigo {}".format(codigo))
        for valor in zip(llaves, inventario[codigo]):
            print(" {}: {}".format(*valor))
```

Al usar `zip()` podemos mezclar el nombre del inventario con su correspodiente valor. Adicional, tambien podemos usarlo para generar un diccionario con el cual se puede acceder por el codigo y el valor buscado

```
def imprime_diccionario(inventario):
    llaves = ["TIPO", "TALLE", "TEMPORADA", "PRECIO", "CANTIDAD"]
    fin_dic = {}
    for codigo in inventario:
        print("Codigo {}".format(codigo)
        for valor in zip(llaves,inventario[codigo]):
            print("{0}: {1}".format(*valor))
            fin_dic[codigo] = valor
```

Comment: @pytonista_entusiasta Algo que se me escapo es que la funci;n zip trabaja de a pares. Por eso ser'ia dif'icil de implementar en este caso.  Keep moving.  TaLot.